# Sphinx, ranking by words count

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I use a sphinx as fulltext search engine, and ranker option is set to **proximity**.

 How can I set as ranker this formula: **proximity** + **count of words in *somecolumn*** / **hit_count**?

I don't know, how can I get words count. 
I've tried to add a column with count of words into the index, but ***somecolumn*** is a huge concate field, and I can't use [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9920337/2254668), because it will be too slow query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[index_field_lengths](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-index-field-lengths) option is just what I needed.