# Update query with spaces

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an update query like this:

```
update table 
set col = 'hello hi' 
where col = 'hi hello'
```

But it is not updating the column which has the value as `'hi    hello'` (more than one space in between `hi` and `hello`). Any suggestions?

Comment: Food for minds see this topic about replacing double spaces http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940646/mysql-how-to-remove-double-or-more-spaces-from-a-string

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. I am using Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres you can use a regular expression for that:

```
update the_table
set col = 'hello hi'
where col ~ '^(hello)\s+(hi)$';
```

The `^` at the beginning and the `$` at the end are needed to avoid updating a row where the column contains e.g. `'here hello hi'` or `'hello hi there'`

If there can be spaces before `hello` or after the `hi` then you can add additional wildcards:

```
update the_table
set col = 'hello hi'
where col ~ '^\s*(hello)\s+(hi)\s*$';
```

Another option would be to use trim() on the column itself with the first regular expression:

```
update the_table
set col = 'hello hi'
where trim(col) ~ '^(hello)\s+(hi)$';
```

More details about regular expressions are in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html

Answer (score 1):

If you need to update every row with various numbers of spaces, you need to use this command instead:

```
update table 
set col = 'hello hi' 
where col LIKE 'hi %hello'
```

The `%` is the placeholder for "any character, any number of repetitions"

Comment: This will also update rows with a `col` value of `'hi SOME_OTHER_STRINGhello'`. Not sure this is what OP was gunning for.

Comment: @Mureinik: true - but most databases that use SQL as their query language don't really have much in terms of regex support, so this is probably the best you can achieve ...

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the problems with wildcards

```
update table 
set col = 'hello hi' 
where LEFT(col, 3) = 'hi ' 
      AND
      RIGHT(col, 6) = ' hello'
      AND
      SUBSTRING(col, 3, LEN(col)-7) = REPLICATE(' ',  LEN(col)-7)
```

Comment: This has the same problem as my answer - it would also update a row with `hi SOME_OTHER_STRING hello`