# Mysql TRIM/REPLACE not working for my Query

Tags: mysql

A column has some string value with lot of spaces and tabs. i am unable to trim these spaces and white spaces.
e.g select trim('column_name') from table_name;

I am not sure how much space is in the string . it may 2 for one string and 12 for other. so replace() is also not working.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940646/mysql-how-to-remove-double-or-more-spaces-from-a-string

Comment: Do you have a known mix of space characters and tab characters `\t`?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer by using the following:

trim(replace(convert(column_name USING ascii),'?',''))

Comment: I am not sure I follow you statement.  But it did lead me to an answer for me.  I had an ascii char 0xC2A0 non-breaking space.  Finally looking up trimming ascii chars I found I could use this stmt
update table set code = trim(char(0xC2A0) from code) where id = 13087;
ref: https://michaelborn.me/entry/trimming-tab-characters-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

MySQL TRIM() does not affect tabs unless they are specified.  If you have multiple mixed tabs and spaces, you might have to replace the tabs with spaces and then trim the results.

```
SELECT TRIM(REPLACE(column_name, CHAR(9), '    ')) FROM table_name;
```